# Git Object Permissions - SSH

Tags: git, ssh, permissions

I have created a bare repository on my server. I am working with another developer and want to share access to this repo. I have set `chgrp -R staff repo.git` as well as `chmod -R 660 repo.git`. I have added both user accounts to the staff group. I have noticed that after pushing to this repo files in the `repo.git/objects` folder have a ownership of `shawn:shawn` vs `shawn:staff`. When my other developer goes to push he is now getting a permission denied error. If i run the `chgrp` this resolves the issue, however, I'm sure this is not how it is meant to work. What is the proper way to handle this scenerio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you created your bare repo?
As mentioned in "[Git - Howto setup Shared Repository with SSH access](http://eagleas.livejournal.com/18907.html) ", you are supposed to declare "`shared=group`" in the [`git init --bare`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init).

```
--shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|0xxx)]
```

> Specify that the Git repository is to be shared amongst several users.
>   This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository.
>   When specified, the config variable "`core.sharedRepository`" is set so that files and directories under `$GIT_DIR` are created with the requested permissions.
>   When not specified, Git will use permissions reported by umas.

Comment: Thanks, that link seemed to help out